# Why is my hybrid (C++, asm) program giving me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, assembly, makefile, x86, nasm

The following is an x86 assembly program meant to be assembled by NASM under 64-bit CentOS over a remote terminal which doesn't have **`gdb`**, and doesn't allow installing it either.

### main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" void looping_test();

int main(void)
{
    looping_test();

    return 0;
}
```

### func.asm

```
extern printf

section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello World!', 20
    helloLen:  equ $-hello

section .text
    global  looping_test

looping_test:       ; print "Hello World" 5 times  

    mov ecx, 0; initialize the counter

    while_loop_lt:
        push    hello
        call    printf

        inc     ecx

        cmp     ecx, 4; This is exit control loop. 
        je  end_while_loop_lt

    end_while_loop_lt:

    ret
```

### makefile

```
CC = g++
ASMBIN = nasm

all : asm cc link
asm : 
    $(ASMBIN) -o func.o -f elf -g -l func.lst func.asm
cc :
    $(CC) -m32 -c -g -O0 main.cpp &> errors.txt
link :
    $(CC) -m32 -g -o test main.o func.o
clean :
    rm *.o
    rm test
    rm errors.txt   
    rm func.lst
```

**Output:**

```
[me@my_remote_server basic-assm]$ make
nasm -o func.o -f elf -g -l func.lst func.asm
g++ -m32 -c -g -O0 main.cpp &> errors.txt
g++ -m32 -g -o test main.o func.o
[me@my_remote_server basic-assm]$ ./test
Segmentation fault
[me@my_remote_server basic-assm]$
```

Why is my program giving me a segmentation fault?

Comment: After the printf you didn't add 4 to ESP to remove the pointer to `hello` from the stack?

Comment: As well ECX is a volatile register and can be clobbered by printf so you should use a register (non-volatile) like EBX.

Comment: You may also need to align the stack on a 16-byte boundary before calling printf

Comment: Try `gdb`, you typoed the command as `gbd`.  Trying to learn asm without a debugger is a big waste of time, so many bugs become simple when you know where to start looking for a problem.  The question would be a much better [mcve] if you used GDB, or at least generate a core file and debug it with GDB on another machine.

Comment: `je  end_while_loop_lt` either jumps or falls through to the next instruction, doesn't matter which.  At that point, your `ret` pops whatever is on the stack into EIP, but it's not your return address.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it was a typo in this question, not on the terminal.

Comment: Always copy/paste your exact code to avoid the risk of errors like that in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done modifications according to *@MichaelPetch* and *@PeterCordes*' comments and got the desired output from the following source code:

### func.asm

```
extern printf

section .data
    hello:     db "Hello World!", 20
    helloLen:  equ $-hello


section .text
    global  looping_test


looping_test:       ; print "Hello World" 5 times  

    mov ebx, 0  ; initialize the counter

    while_loop_lt:
        push    hello
        call    printf
        add     esp, 4

        inc     ebx

        cmp     ebx, 5          ; This is exit control loop. 
        je  end_while_loop_lt

        jmp     while_loop_lt   

    end_while_loop_lt:

    ret
```

Comment: Use `jne while_loop_lt` like a normal person, instead of conditionally jumping over a `jmp`.  Also, you destroy the caller's `ebx` without saving/restoring it, so you're lucky if the caller doesn't crash.  Also you call `printf` with ESP not aligned by 16.  (It was aligned by 16 before the `call` that called this function, so it takes 12 more bytes of ESP offset to realign it, but you're only doing 4 (with 1 push).)  Saving/restoring EBX would get you closer, then you just need one more dummy push/pop in the function prologue/epilogue.  (Or `sub/add esp,4`).

Comment: Try writing it in C and looking at the output for `gcc -O2 -m32 -S -masm=intel` (which uses MASM-like GAS syntax, not NASM syntax, but it's pretty close.)  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  Although gcc will probably fully unroll 5 iteration-loop.  Maybe just change the loop count to 10000 to see how gcc optimizes the function while obeying the ABI / calling convention.